# Turn ON/OFF allcaps font in Keynote

Tags: fonts, iwork-keynote, capslock, typeface

Currently some themes have all-caps for some textelements on the master.

I can't locate where I can toggle between all-caps, and a regular typeface.

Any clues?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select the text and go to the menu Format > Font > Capitals (last one in list) and select None. (I may be off a little with the spelling as I translated this back to English.)

Answer (score 2):

`Format > Fonts > Capitalization > All Caps` is the right way to make all caps. It seems there is no other shorter way to do it.